# Populate listview with time by pressing a button in Android

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

Can anyone explain how to achieve this requirement?

Here is my requirement:

- I should be able to dynamically add new elements by pressing a button which shows the time when button is pressed.

I know this is the silly question, but i need to solve this problem. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: @codeMagic  first read my question properly than marked as duplicate

Comment: I did read your question carefully first. If you feel it isn't a dupe, then edit with *why* you think it isn't and **add code that you have tried so far and explain what isn't working**.

Comment: I want to add listview element which shows shows the time when button is pressed in the TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.setOnCLickListener(clickListener);

View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdaper(this, new ArrayList<>());
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
};
```

Comment: IgorB I know this method, but i need to add current time in the listview element

Comment: Some you have some model that you populate in ListView. At any time just go throw all element in adapter  `mAdapter.getItem()` and update time what you want to populate. after this just call      `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by telling the adapter of the listview that the data has changed after adding the new element.

```
listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```